# What is the best way to parse Facebook friends string?

Tags: php, string, facebook, parsing, facebook-graph-api

In facebook SDK for PHP, after user authentication, I request the user's friends field:

```
$userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
$friends = $userNode->getField('friends');
```

And $friends turns out to be a string in the following format:

```
"[{\"name\":\"Dean Winchester\",\"id\":\"940000000000011\"},{\"name\":\"Jon Snow\",\"id\":\"8666666666666666661\"}]"
```

What is the best way to parse this, in order to get just the facebook ids? Var_dump indicates it is a string indeed, not an object, neither an array.

I suppose the answer will be very simple, but I'm a newbie and have never dealt with this format. And I don't want to do a lousy job using str_replace or something like that when an acknowledged method to parse this probably exists. :)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use $userNode->getPropertyAsArray('friends') instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in json format. Use `json_decode` to parse it into a stdClass object or an associative array [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)